# Can one pull a diagonal matrix forward in a symmetric expression?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have matrices $A,B$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ with all diagonal elements positive. If I have an expression like

$$ A^TB^TDBA$$

Can we pull $D$ into the front, i.e.

$$A^TB^TDBA= DA^TB^TBA$$

Comment: A diagonal matrix only commutes with other diagonal matrices. So this  works if BA happens to be diagonal.

Comment: Try some random matrices.

Comment: The center of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the set of diagonal matrices *with constant diagonal*. So you're allowed to do this if every nonzero entry of $D$ is identical, but otherwise not.